# Why completionHandler block does not respond?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, alamofire, completionhandler

My task is, to load JSON via Alamofire, fill my array and just later to show it inside of `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {` but I have a problem, because those block starts before my array was filled, so I get a crash, that my array is empty.

I thought that I can solve this problem with the completionHandler as:

```
func abcd(completion: (() -> Void)) {
    let getMyProfileURL = "\(self.property.host)\(self.property.getMyProfile)"
    Alamofire.request(.POST, getMyProfileURL, parameters: self.userParameters.profileParameteres, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
        do {
            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

            if json["user"].count > 0 {
                self.profileDetails.append(ProfileDetailsModel(json: json["user"]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

later, I call it with:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    self.abcd {
        print("SUCCESS")
        print(self.profileDetails)
    }
}
```

but it does not print my `completionHandler` code `prints`. Why? What is the problem and how can I fix it?

P.S If you can offer me better solution for my task it would be great!

Comment: initialise the array when you get response and then reload the collectionview .

Comment: you need to reload the collection view, once you are done with the asynchronous data request

Comment: you didn't call the completion block in the function `abcd`, that's why it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @TangZijian a little bit detailed, please

Comment: @JohnDoe in `abcd`, you need to call `completion()`. `completion` is an function argument, and you never call it in `abcd`

Answer (score 1):

Reload the CollectionView in main thread, once you are done with the asynchronous data request.

```
func abcd(completion: (() -> Void)) {
    let getMyProfileURL = "\(self.property.host)\(self.property.getMyProfile)"
    Alamofire.request(.POST, getMyProfileURL, parameters: self.userParameters.profileParameteres, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
        do {
            let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

            if json["user"].count > 0 {
                self.profileDetails.append(ProfileDetailsModel(json: json["user"]))
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                   collectionView.reloadData()
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about this method of UICollectionView! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Response to 'why it does not print completionHandler code': because you never call the completion handler in `abcd`. The correct code would be:

```
func abcd(completion: (() -> Void)) {
let getMyProfileURL = "\(self.property.host)\(self.property.getMyProfile)"
Alamofire.request(.POST, getMyProfileURL, parameters: self.userParameters.profileParameteres, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
    do {
        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)

        if json["user"].count > 0 {
            self.profileDetails.append(ProfileDetailsModel(json: json["user"]))
        }  
        completion()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: and @Kumar KL gives the correct answer about reloading collection view after data is fetched.